# jquery toggle content inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to swap out content within a button that toggles a nav collapse.

I currently have the following code;

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i> Expand</button>
//in js script
$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#page").toggleClass("toggled-2");

});
```

I want to be able to change the content within  to be;

```
<i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i> Collapse
```

This needs to be toggled however, so when you click collapse, it changes back to its original state

Can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/oaftwxt2/

```
var clicked = 0;

$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#page").toggleClass("toggled-2");

    if(clicked == 0){    
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i> Collapse');
        clicked = 1;
    }else{
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i> Expand');
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `firstElementChild` to get the `<i>` and then change its `className` according to the actual `className`, so it will toggle between the two classes you want:

```
$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var i = this.firstElementChild;
  i.className = i.className === 'fa fa-expand' ? 'fa fa-compress' : 'fa fa-expand';
  $("#page").toggleClass("toggled-2");
});
```

Comment: Watch out for `.className` you might wanna use `.hasClass(class)` instead

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery for that, since I can do it with vanilla JS as easy as.

Comment: And what happens if I somewhere else do: `my_i_el.className += ' shit-happends'`

Comment: Also note that `firstElementChild` is first supported in IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild

Comment: That will not happen with a font awesome icon.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, and since Microsoft is dropping IE8 support, I have absolutely no idea why someone would reinvent the wheel for doing that.

Comment: btw, instead of commenting here, you can also give a better answer for the OP, and for sure he'll decide what he likes better :) - and if your answer is better than mine, I'll be happy to give it an upvote, and remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "Expand") {
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-expand").addClass("fa-compress");
        $(this).contents()[2].data = "Collapse";
    } else {
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-compress").addClass("fa-expand");
        $(this).contents()[2].data = "Expand";
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yy4nLzfm/)